# Using \newcommand to shortcut math mode $...$ with text spacing issues

Tags: spacing, formatting

(New to LaTeX, so please explain solutions in detail and with examples)

I have many N_{(s)}, N_{(s,a)}, R_{(s)}, R_{(s,a)}, etc in my report.

These are also often integrated with other equations: `$Q_{(s)}=\frac{R_{(s)}}{N_{(s)}}=\frac{rewards}{visits}$`

I want to use newcommands like `\newcommand{\Ns}{$N_{(s)}$}`, but when I integrated the shortcut `\Ns` in my code with text surrounding it, there is no space between `\Ns` and the letters after it.

For example, using the newcommand and the following in my LaTeX file:

```
\newcommand{\Ns}{$N_{(s)}$}
          ........
          ........
Technology \Ns has given us
```

gives a PDF result of:

[image]

Lastly, how would I integrate \Ns with other equations? 
I want something like

```
$\Qs=\frac{\Rs}{\Ns}=\frac{rewards}{visits}$
```

Comment: Use `\ensuremath{...}` instead of `$...$`. For the spacing issue, check `xspace`, there are also many alternatives to `xspace` implemented on this site.

Comment: The standard approach is to invoke it as `\Ns{}` with the space following the closing brace.

Comment: Or `{\Ns} `, depending on your style. Anyway I ended up with `xspace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend not putting `$...$` inside these macros, both because I think that it is always better to explicitly enter and exit math-mode and because it will break syntax highlighting in your editor. As it pointed out in the comments, if you really want to do this then use `\ensuremath`.

Depending on how often you use these commands, with the `\Rs` macros I would use an optional argument:

```
\newcommand\Rs[1][s]{R_{(#1)}}
```

Now, `$\Rs$` will produce `$R_{(s)}$` and $\Rs[s,a]$ will produce $R_{(s,a)}$.

Finally, you don't want to write `\frac{rewards}{visits}` as the letters in rewards and visits will look like variables multiplied together. Instead, you should use `\frac{\text{rewards}}{\text{visits}}$. The`\text` command comes from the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

For completeness, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\Ns[1][s]{N_{(#1)}}
\newcommand\Rs[1][s]{R_{(#1)}}
\newcommand\Qs[1][s]{Q_{(#1)}}

\begin{document}

  $\Qs=\frac{\Rs}{\Ns}=\frac{\text{rewards}}{\text{visits}}$

\end{document}
```